Justify the application of Scheffé's Lemma in Giorgio Letta's "Introduzione ai processi stocastici"
I am really close to understanding a fascinating proof that uses Scheffé's lemma in an unexpected way! I am reading the chapter about non-uniformly integrable martingales in Giorgio Letta's book Introduzione ai processi stocastici. Although I need clarification on a small detail, I feel it's necessary to write out the whole proof because the author hasn't been very clear, and a little context will help.
I don't mean to criticize the author—it's impossible to include every detail in a book. Here is the link to the original article by Scheffé.
Here is the theorem.
Prerequisites and Notations:

$(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ i.i.d with law $\mu$, where $\mu$ is not the trivial law, and let $P = \bigotimes^{\mathbb{N}} \mu $ on $(E^{\mathbb{N}},\bigotimes^{\mathbb{N}} \mathcal{E})$, where $(E,\mathcal{E})$ is the measurable space where $\mu$ is defined.

Established Facts:

$Y_{n} = \prod_{k = 1}^{n} f(X_{k})$ is a martingale with respect to the natural filtration: $\mathcal{F}_{n} := \sigma (\{ X_{i} : 1 \leq i \leq n\})$, where $f$ is a density function on $(E, \mathcal{E}, \mu).$
Scheffé's Lemma: Take a family of densities $p_{n}(x)$ defined on the same probability space that converge to a function $p$. Then if $p$ is a density, the $p_{n}$ converge in $L^1$ to $p$.

Theorem:
With the preceding notations, let $\nu$ denote the law $f \cdot \mu$: the law of density $f$ with respect to $\mu,$ and let $Q = \bigotimes^{\mathbb{N}} \nu$. Let $\{ Y_{n} \}$ be the martingale defined as $Y_{n} = \prod_{i=1}^{n}f(X_i)$ above and $T$ a stopping time. Define
\begin{gather*}
Y_{T} := \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} Y_{n} \cdot I_{\{ T=n \}},
\end{gather*}
then the following properties are true:

The measure $Y_T \cdot P$ coincides with $I_{\{ T < +\infty \}} \cdot Q$ on the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}_{T}$.
If $T$ is finite (not a.e finite!), then the stopped martingale $Y^{|T}$ is closed.

Proof:
If $T = n$ almost surely, then $\mathcal{F}_{T} = \mathcal{F}_n$. In this particular case, it is enough to prove that $Y_{n} \cdot P$ coincides with $Q$ on $\mathcal{F}_{n}$. This is true because the equality holds on the rectangles:
\begin{gather*}
H = \bigcap_{i=1}^{n} \{ X_i \in A_i \}, \quad A_{i} \in \mathcal{E}, \quad \forall i = 1, \dots, n.
\end{gather*}
\begin{gather*}
\int_H Y_n \, dP = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \int_{A_i} f \, d\mu = \prod_{i=1}^{n}\nu(A_i) = Q(H).
\end{gather*}
The general case follows from the equalities:
\begin{gather*}
\int_{H \cap \{ T = n \}} Y_T \, dP = \int_{H \cap \{ T = n \}} Y_n
 \, dP = Q(H \cap \{ T = n \}) \quad \forall i = 1, \dots, n, \quad \forall H \in \mathcal{F}_T,
\end{gather*}
and by summing we obtain:
\begin{gather*}
\int_{H} Y_{T} \, dP = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \int_{H \cap \{ T = n\}} Y_{n} \, dP \\
= \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} Q(\{ T =n  \} \cap H) = Q(\{ T < +\infty \} \cap H).
\end{gather*}
Now, here's the part I did not fully understand. The proof hinges on proving that $(Y_{n \wedge T})_{n}$ and $Y_{T}$ are densities with respect to $P$, and I am not sure how the author justifies this fact. After that, all that's left is to use Scheffé's Lemma: since $T$ is almost surely finite, $Y_{n \wedge T} \to Y_{T}$ almost everywhere.
My Attempt to Justify that the Variables are Densities:
For $Y_{n \wedge T}$, I think it has something to do with partitioning $\Omega$ into the disjoint union of the sets $\{ T = k\}$, but I couldn't conclude.
As for $Y_{T}$, we have from the previous point that
\begin{gather*}
\int_{\Omega} Y_T \, dP = Q(\{ T < +\infty\}).
\end{gather*}
I would be done if $Q(\{ T = \infty\}) = 0$. This makes sense because $P(\{ T = \infty\}) = 0$, by hypothesis.
I tried to test the equality on the rectangles:
\begin{gather*}
Q(\{ T = \infty \} \cap A_{1} \times \dots \times A_{n}) = \int_{A_1 \times \dots \times A_n} \mathbb{1}_{\{ T = \infty \}} f(X_{1}(\omega)) \cdot \dots \cdot f(X_{n}(\omega)) \, dP(\omega) = 0.
\end{gather*}
Is this reasoning correct? I am particularly perplexed about the penultimate equality.
Thank you in advance!

The function $f$ is a mystery. Do you intend that $Y_n=\prod_{k=1}^n f(X_k)$?
Also, for $(Y_n)$ to be a martingale you'll need $E[Y_1]=1$. I'm guessing that also $f\ge 0$. If so then each $Y_{n\wedge T}$ is a "density" being a non-negative measurable function with $P$ integral equal to $1$. Likewise for $Y_T$ when $T$ is finite.
The computation you exhibit shows that for each $n$, $Q(A\cap\{T=n\})=E^P(1_A\cdot Y_T\cdot 1_{\{T=n\}})$ if $A\in\mathcal F_n$ is a rectangle. This equality is then true for general $A\in \mathcal F_n$, by the monotone class theorem. Finally, if $P(T<\infty)=1$ and $A\in\mathcal F_T$, then $A\cap\{T=n\}\in\mathcal F_n$ for each $n$, so summing the preceding identity you get $Q(A)=E^P(1_A\cdot Y_T)$. That is, $Y_T$ is the density for $Q$ with respect to $P$.
Here's another way to state Scheffé's lemma that might be clearer. On a measure space $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ consider measurable functions $g_n$ and $g$ mapping $E$ to $[0,\infty]$. Suppose that $g_n\to g$, $\lambda$-a.e.,
and that $\int_E g_n\,d\lambda\to\int_E g\,d\lambda$ (all of these integrals being finite by hypothesis). Then $g_n$ converges to $g$ in $L^1(\lambda)$.
The proof is more or less the same as that given by Scheffé: Integrate the identity
$|g-g_n|=2(g-g_n)^+-g+g_n$ (here $b^+:=\max(b,0)$ is the positive part of $b$), and note that
$$
\lim_n\int_E(g-g_n)^+\,d\lambda=0,
$$
by Dominated Convergence because $0\le(g-g_n)^+\le g$.
The special case in the original paper is when $\int_E g_n\,d\lambda=\int_E g_n\,d\lambda=1$ for all $n$.

you were right about the $Y_{n}'s$! I was confused by the previous result where the $Y_{n}$ was defined as the product of the $X_n's.$
Now it should be all correct, right? But I still can see it why the stopped martiganle has all the expectations equal to one. This is my reasoning
$$
\int_{\Omega} Y_{T \cap n} dP = \int_{\Omega \cap { T \geq n} } \prod_{i=1}^{n} f(X_{i})  dP  + \sum_{l=1}^{k} \int_{\Omega \cap { T = l}}  \prod_{i=1}^{l} f(X_{i}) dP
$$
What am I missing?

I know the definition of a density. My problem is that by summing the inequalities you obtain $Q(A \cap {T < +\infty} ),$ thus to prove that $int_A Y_T dP$ is a probability measure we should prove that $Q({ T <+ \infty } ) = 1$.

Example: $f(X_k)$ is $0$ or $2$, with probability $1/2$ each. Then $(Y_n)$ is a martingale with mean $1$. Now take $T:=\min(n\ge 1: Y_n=0)$. Evidently $P(T<\infty) =1$. But $E^P(Y_T) =0$, so the stopped martingale $(Y_{n\wedge T})$ is not closed. In this example $Q(T<\infty) =0$.
I'm suspicious of the second statement of the Theorem, unless "$T$ is almost surely finite" means "$Q(T<\infty)=1$" (not "$P(T<\infty) =1$").

that's a bingo! The precise statement was $T$ finite, not almost everywhere finite! Given that the author is really precise with words I think he meant finite for every $\omega$ in the probability space! So we can assume that $T$ is finite according to every measure! Don't you think?

One last thing, I verified every fact in your counterexample except $Q({ T < +\infty } ) = 0$. The difficulty is that the measure q is a tensor product of an infinite amount of measures. Does this mean I should reduce to a finite amount by testing the statement on the rectangles?

sorry, what about the expectations of the stopped martingale. I keep doing the same reasoning without getting any results like the mad man in the old saying.

A stopped martingale is still a martingale, so $E(Y_{T\wedge n}) =E(Y_1)$ for all $n\ge 1$.
